# Logic Proof of satisfiability by resolution refutation- example seems wrong

Tags: logic

I am trying to follow an example in a tutorial letter but I am not sure if there is an error in it (the negation bars are meant to be above the letters following them:

Say you are required to prove that the set of clauses {pq ̄r,pq,p ̄r ̄} is satisfiable by means of resolution refutation.
1. p ̄qr
2. pq
3.  ̄p ̄r
4. pr     1, 2.
5. q ̄r    2, 3.

IS it allowed, to use clause 2 in more than one resolution? First it is used to resolve clause 1 and 2 leaving pr, but then it is used again to remove the p's leaving q ̄r. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The idea is to try all pairs of clauses with complementary literals.